# Why does my Java socket client code loops forever without ever throwing an IO Exception even though the server on the other side is already dead?

Tags: java, sockets

I would expect the line `pw.println("Hello")` to throw an IOException after I kill the server on the other side. But no, it keeps sending forever. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SendBlockingLines {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 55555);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(true) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) pw.println("Hello");
            System.out.print('.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That sucks. Which class should I use to send data then?

Comment: Note that if the remote peer is *killed* abruptly, there is no indication sent to the surviving peer that the connection is gone, so it may take awhile for the OS of the surviving peer to detect that the connection is really dead. Until then, I/O operations continue to succeed at the OS level - sends are buffered until the buffer fills up, and reads will keep waiting for new data that will never arrive.